# ActionScript3: How to search an XML list?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I have the following XML variable:

```
public var Country:XML=new XML(
    <countries>
         <country code="US" iso="840" label="United States" />
         <country code="CA" iso="124" label="Canada" />
         <country code="GB" iso="826" label="United Kingdom" />
         ...
    </countries>);
```

How would I loop through the list to find the index number corresponding to the value stored in String variable `myCountry`? For example, if

```
var myCountry:String = "Canada";
```

How to create a loop that returns an index value of 1, meaning Canada is the 2nd element in the XML list?

Or, maybe looping isn't necessary if the index value of 1 can be returned some other way. I tried:

```
var desiredIndex:int = Country.country.(@label==myCountry)
```

but it gives the error `No such variable: @label`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do what you want:

```
var index:int = 0;
for each (var country:XML in Country.country)
{
    if (country.@label == myCountry)
        break;

    index++;
}
```

(the `Country` variable should be named `countries` or something similar... conventionally capitalised names are used for classes only)

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you mama pitufo! It works perfectly. Do you know whether it's possible to do all in one line as I tried above?

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence returns an XMLList, not an int variable.

childIndex method returns the index of a node inside an XML tree:

var desiredIndex:int = Country.country.(@label.toString() == myCountry).childIndex();